# User rights on mounted USB-Stick

Tags: mount, media

I have an issue regarding User Rights on mounted USB-Device using my Raspberry Pi with Raspbian/Samba-Server.

In the folder "/media" there are 2 subfolders as the following

```
drwx------ 45 pi pi 8192 ADAC_STICK   (I think this one was created automatically)
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 usbadac   (Created this on my own with mkdir)
```

The USB-Stick called "ADAC_STICK" is mounted to /media/usbadac with

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o uid=pi,gid=pi,umask=0000 /dev/sda1 /media/usbadac
```

This folder /media/usbadac has NOW following rights (via "ls -la" in "/media")

```
drwx------ 45 pi pi usbadac
```

If I connect via Local Networking (intern IP) as user "pi", it works pretty fine.

**Now comes the problem:** I want to use a second Account "family" for other Users in the Network to connect to /media/usbadac/Family

So I created the System-User and Samba-User "family" by

```
sudo adduser --diabled-login family
sudo smbpasswd -a family
```

Using this account to connect to Samba (e.g. by Android-Device or Windows via Local Network) doesn't work by giving the error, that the account is not permitted.

In my opinion, the rights for the folder /media/usbadac has to be e.g.

```
drwxrwxrwx pi pi usbadac
drwxr-xr-x pi pi usbadac
```

Using `chmod 777 /media/usbadac` didn't work.

Samba Config:

```
[USB-ADAC]
path = /media/usbadac
writeable = yes
guest ok = no
valid users = pi

[FAMILY_USB-ADAC]
path = /media/usbadac/Family
writeable = yes
guest ok = no
valid users = pi,family
```

So what to do now? Something I forgot to do?

Comment: Try after adding 'family' to group 'pi'

Comment: @Ron Tried to change the standard group via "sudo usermod -g pi family" - Didn't work, I think because the Group "pi" has also the rights "---" for the folder "/media/usbadac"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that your USB stick holds a VFAT partition which is not compatible with POSIX access rights (actually, it does not support access rights at all, unlike NTFS). So when the kernel mounts your USB stick in `/media/usbadac`, it will apply recursively the virtual access rights that are defined in the options of the `/etc/fstab` line. These access rights are then immutable, until you unmount and remount with different options.

So you need to grant more lax access rights, for instance you could create a UNIX group called `sambausers`, put both `pi` and `family` in this group, and then mount the USB stick with the said group and a better mask:

```
groupadd sambausers
usermod -a -G sambausers pi
usermod -a -G sambausers family

sudo mount -t vfat -o uid=pi,gid=sambausers,fmask=0113,dmask=0002 /dev/sda1 /media/usbadac
```

I think that you changed some settings while writing your answer because the mounted USB stick should have rights `drwxrwxrwx` instead of `drwx------` with a `umask=0000`. I changed the masks for a more fine-grained access rights policy (we distinguish between files and directories).

The Samba shares should work as-is (provided that you can nest Samba shares, I don't think there's anything preventing it).

Comment: Thanks for this great answer!
I just reorganized my file system (subfolders,...), used NTFS, used /etc/fstab and it works perfectly!

Comment: Just for the record, the access rights scheme used by NTFS is not compatible with POSIX either so the same restrictions apply. But it's probably a good move to switch to NTFS if only because it can store files larger than 4GB.